# Removing empty node created by XSL

Tags: xslt

I want remove an element created by xsl. I am checking for children after creating an element .For example

```
<projectRisks>    (element to be removed if it empty after creation)

 <for-each risk>

  <if riskid=projid >

      COPY RISK

  </if >

 </foreach>

<projectRisks>
```

After completing this, if there are no children for projectRisks, i need to remove it.
I tried all the solutions provided here. But, as the projectRisks created here in xsl, not able to remove it.

here im providing sample XML

```
 <addProjectDetail>
<uniqueProjectId>142</uniqueProjectId>
</addProjectDetail>
<addProjectDetail>
<uniqueProjectId>915</uniqueProjectId>
</addProjectDetail>
<addProjectDetail>
<uniqueProjectId>100</uniqueProjectId>
</addProjectDetail>
  <addProjectRisks>
    <addProjectRisk>
        <uniqueProjectId>142</uniqueProjectId>
        <agencyProjectRiskId>852</agencyProjectRiskId>              
    </addProjectRisk>
   <addProjectRisk>
    <uniqueProjectId>915</uniqueProjectId>
    <agencyProjectRiskId>853</agencyProjectRiskId>  
    </addProjectRisk>   
   </addProjectRisks>
```

Resultant xml looks like

```
   <addProjectDetail>
   <uniqueProjectId>142</uniqueProjectId>
      </addProjectDetail>
<addProjectRisks>
    <addProjectRisk>
        <uniqueProjectId>142</uniqueProjectId>
        <agencyProjectRiskId>852</agencyProjectRiskId>              
    </addProjectRisk>
</addProjectRisks>
<addProjectDetail>
<uniqueProjectId>915</uniqueProjectId>
</addProjectDetail>
<addProjectRisks>
    <addProjectRisk>
        <uniqueProjectId>915</uniqueProjectId>
         <agencyProjectRiskId>853</agencyProjectRiskId>             
    </addProjectRisk>
</addProjectRisks>
 <addProjectDetail>
<uniqueProjectId>100</uniqueProjectId>
</addProjectDetail>
```

In the above xml, there 3 codes, 142, 915 and 100.
Matching to 142 and 915 there 2 risks and for 100 there are no risks
So for 100 it should not create a addProjectRisks element

Comment: Instead of thinking of removing the element _after_ its creation if...you should think of adding the element only if...

Comment: It's not possible to help you more without meaningful data.

Comment: Kirill, The data in xml is very confidential. So i can not provide you the xml but can give you idea on it.

I have a ProjectRisks element in which many Risk elemets are there with different projids. i need to place all risks with my ids into a ProjectRisks element i.e i will create many ProjectRisks elements in different places having risk ids matching to my id. 
Actually i have one more idea also. If i can find out a atleast one risk id matching to my id in the whole xml document, then i will create projectRisks element else i ll not create at all. 
But how to find out from 100s of risk ids?

Comment: Provide simplified sample (not real) XML, which shows your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this transform, for which I've used *modes* so that it simplifies integration in your current (not shown) stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="ProjectRiskById" match="addProjectRisk" use="uniqueProjectId"/>

    <xsl:template match="addProjectDetail">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ProjectRiskById',uniqueProjectId)[1]" 
            mode="add"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="addProjectRisk" mode="add">
        <addProjectRisks>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('ProjectRiskById',uniqueProjectId)"/>
        </addProjectRisks>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on the following input sample (changed to make it well-formed by adding a top-most element and to make it cover more cases):

```
<xml>
    <addProjectDetail>
        <uniqueProjectId>142</uniqueProjectId>
    </addProjectDetail>
    <addProjectDetail>
        <uniqueProjectId>915</uniqueProjectId>
    </addProjectDetail>
    <addProjectDetail>
        <uniqueProjectId>100</uniqueProjectId>
    </addProjectDetail>

    <addProjectRisks>
        <addProjectRisk>
            <uniqueProjectId>142</uniqueProjectId>
            <agencyProjectRiskId>852</agencyProjectRiskId>              
        </addProjectRisk>
        <addProjectRisk>
            <uniqueProjectId>915</uniqueProjectId>
            <agencyProjectRiskId>853</agencyProjectRiskId>  
        </addProjectRisk>   
                <addProjectRisk>
            <uniqueProjectId>915</uniqueProjectId>
            <agencyProjectRiskId>857</agencyProjectRiskId>  
        </addProjectRisk> 
    </addProjectRisks>
</xml>
```

Produces this fragment:

```
<addProjectDetail>
   <uniqueProjectId>142</uniqueProjectId>
</addProjectDetail>
<addProjectRisks>
   <addProjectRisk>
      <uniqueProjectId>142</uniqueProjectId>
      <agencyProjectRiskId>852</agencyProjectRiskId>
   </addProjectRisk>
</addProjectRisks>
<addProjectDetail>
   <uniqueProjectId>915</uniqueProjectId>
</addProjectDetail>
<addProjectRisks>
   <addProjectRisk>
      <uniqueProjectId>915</uniqueProjectId>
      <agencyProjectRiskId>853</agencyProjectRiskId>
   </addProjectRisk>
   <addProjectRisk>
      <uniqueProjectId>915</uniqueProjectId>
      <agencyProjectRiskId>857</agencyProjectRiskId>
   </addProjectRisk>
</addProjectRisks>
<addProjectDetail>
   <uniqueProjectId>100</uniqueProjectId>
</addProjectDetail>
```